# Design distorted while uploading big file name in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, firefox

I am uploading a file with too big name in firefox using asp file uploader.
Problem is that the design gets distorted while it is working fine in other browsers.
screenshot of firefox-
[image]

In Chrome-

[image]

How to set browser compatibility of file name inside file uploader?

Comment: use Truncate String (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) with Ellipsis for file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set fix width in File Uploader as:
style="width:300px". This will not distort the design and will restrict the filename within the given width limit